# I think our order (to be) mixed up with someone else's

Tags: verbs

Is this sentence well-formed English with or without "to be"?

> A shipment of books just arrived, but I think our order (to be) mixed up with someone else's.

Where you can keep the bracketed "to be" or leave it out, says the writer of this sentence.

FYI, this sentence has been given as a correct example sentence to illustrate the usage of the verb "think" in this [site](http://www.kpsat.co.kr/user/es/prof/prof_qna_view.asp?Tmp1=nbzeus&id=8080669&vid=8081152&CP=1&Search=&search_word=).

Comment: You can leave it as is, or use a couple different tenses for "to be", but the verb "be" cannot be left out here.

Comment: The idiomatic, informal way to phrase it would be "I think our order **got** mixed up with someone else's."  But I can't see it being correct either with "to be" or without it.  Maybe the author meant that you can use *some conjugation of* "to be" there?  It would be acceptable to say  "our order **was** mixed up with someone else's".

Comment: If you drop the (to be) altogether, you get something of the effect of "the flour mixed with the egg", except it doesn't really work when you use "mixed *up*".

Comment: If you treat the whole of "mixed up with someone else's" as an adjective, it sort of works. It's not pretty though.

Answer (score -1):

No. That construction is found (though it's rather literary) but only with "think" in the sense of "judge" or "evaluate", not in the sense of "believe" or "have the opionion".

In this sense you need a finite "that" clause (though 'that' may be omitted):

> I think (that) our order has been mixed up with someone else's.

Comment: -1 no references, no illustrating why the OP's example cannot be *judging*